# productions link not black with white background

Tags: css

```css
.navigation {
  padding: 40px 0px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  }

.navigation a {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 100px 35px 0px 35px;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.75;
  font-family: impact;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
}

#productions a {
    color: black !important;
    background: white !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <div id="productions">
    <a href="./productions.html">Mes productions</a>
  </div>
  <a href="../DJ/DJ.html">DJ</a>
  <a target="_blank" href="../CV.pdf">Mon CV</a>
  <a href="../contact/contact.html">Me contacter</a>
</div>
```

my links are white with black background but i want one of them (production) to be black with white background. i did that:
weird thing is that it worked on an other page with the link dj and i just copy paste my code and changed the id dj to productions but it doesn't work anymore. i must have made some mistake but i can figure out where.

```
 <div class="navigation">
  <div id="productions">
    <a href="./productions.html">Mes productions</a>
  </div>
  <a href="../DJ/DJ.html">DJ</a>
  <a target="_blank" href="../CV.pdf">Mon CV</a>
  <a href="../contact/contact.html">Me contacter</a>
</div>

.navigation {
  padding: 40px 0px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  }

.navigation a {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 100px 35px 0px 35px;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.75;
  font-family: impact;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
}

#productions a {
    color: black !important;
    background: white !important;
}
```

Comment: Given the code you've provided, the intended result should work as expected - as it does in your code snippet

Comment: thank you but i don't see what you changed

Comment: It's a conspiracy...

Comment: Your code seems to work fine and nobody edited it (the edit you mention was to correct a typo, code wasn't touched). If this code doesn't work in some of your pages then you have *another* code in that pages that make it fail.